# OpenFileDialog ограничения

Tags: c#, wpf

Господа нуждаюсь в помощи, в c# WPF есть OpenFileDialog и мне нужно ограничить директорию выбора файла, то бишь юзер не должен выходить за пределы определенной директории!

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, такой фичи из коробки нет. Но вопрос в том, а для чего вам это нужно? Если вы хотите закрыть доступ юзеру к каталогам, это нужно делать при помощи установки прав доступа на каталоги/файлы. Если вы хотите, чтобы юзер не выбрал неправильный файл, сделайте проверку после выбора.

Comment: Благодарю, ну получается мне нужно чтобы было видно только директорию флешки и больше никаких файлов.

Comment: @Lifan стандартным `OpenFileDialog`'ом такого не добиться. Единственное, что вы можете сделать, это выполнять вызов `ShowDialog()` в цикле `while(true)` и в случае, если пользователь ввел неверный файл, выводить сообщение об ошибке(стандартный `MessageBox` подойдет).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такой возможности совершенно точно нет.

Более того, по правому клику можно вызвать обычный проводник из любого стандартного диалога открытия/сохранения файла. Что в свою очередь позволяет попасть на рабочий стол, даже если приложение запускается в качестве среды, вместо рабочего стола. Да это дыра в безопасности Windows и ей уже много-много лет. Хоть и не критичная дыра, но дыра, в свое время доставила мне массу "удовольствий".

Варианта у вас всего два:

- вооружаемся знаниями и пишем собственный диалог под собственные потребности. Не очень долго, зато потом можно использовать везде, где потребуется. Особенно если сохранить его в отдельной библиотеке.
- настраиваем права пользователя таким образом, чтобы он ничего кроме допустимого в файловой системе не видел и не имел доступа на прямое чтение. Только скрытие помогает плохо, т.к. в том же диалоге можно ввести адрес и вручную. Можно завести для программы отдельного пользователя с порезанными правами, но если планируется, что пользователь (человек) сам будет запускать программу, то это лишено смысла.